# Android back pressed without refresh activity

Tags: android, android-listview, activity-lifecycle

I have 2 activities which one activity leads to the other activity.
The first activity present a listview and the items click leads to the second activity.
When I click the back button I get back to the first activity but the list reload and scroll up to the first item. I want the list to stay at its place after I get back to it.

Comment: The list get its item from Parse.com.
I dont want to save the data I want the previos activity won't reload.

Comment: don't finish your first activity when you go to second activity by clicking on list item. and in the second activity finish this activity on back pressed.

Comment: Thats what im doing and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If you call finish() in activity A when openig the new Activity B on back press you will call onCreate() of activity A to avoid this avoid calling finish() in activity A in your onItemClickListner()of activity A and record tge position of tge click in Activity A, in which case calling the back press in Activity B will cll for tge onResume() in activity A where in you could call For a direct scroll:

```
getListView().setSelection(<position>);
```

Or For a smooth scroll:

```
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(<position>);
```

Answer (score -1):

when you press back you call oncreate() on that activity so everything reload
you could use :

```
   getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(yourpostion);
```

and think about using fragments for another way around it .
and recyclerview is advised .

Comment: I cant get the position because I use a costum adapter

Comment: @ZachBublil mmm you should be apple to get the position if you added an onClickListner to move from activity a to b using the list, and some cod could help your question ,even if it's not by me :)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't call `finish()` on Activity A, even if you go to Activity B and come back, Activity A should not call the whole `onCreate()` again.

If you take a look at the life cycle of Activities, it will put Activity A in `onPause()` and probably `onStop()` depending on what you are doing on Activity B and how you defined `launchMode` in AndroidManifest.xml.

So when you are calling `startActivity(..)`, don't call `finish()`. Otherwise it will load everything again to draw the Activity A.

Another possible way is using

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  ..
}
```

OR you can use `SharedPreference`.

Once fetching data from Parse.com is over (like `onPostExecute()` of `AsyncTask`), you can read the data passed from Activity B to relocate the user to the list where they were.

EDIT:

Read [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) about how to "come back" to the activity you were in, too.

Comment: I cant get the list position because the intent is in the list costum adapter.